# C++: 32 bit to 64 bit migration

Tags: c++, macos, 64-bit

I am working on a project of migrating 32 bit `C++` code to work on both 32 and 64-bit mode on `Mac OS X`. I am confused in certain things. For instance, consider the following lines of code-

```
long* buffer = new long[VAL];
long var = buffer[0];
```

Now, I know that `sizeof(long)` would return `4` in 32-bit and `8` in 64-bit. So, I am confused as to what should be the replacement for the above two lines in general so that these lines work correctly both in 32-bit as well as 64-bit mode.

This may sound like a trivial question but I am just no able to make any progress in such kind issues which are plentiful in the project I am working on.

Comment: Why do you need a replacement? What's wrong with those lines?

Comment: Variables which will be dependent on `var` will return different values on 32-bit and 64-bit modes and the code will become inconsistent.

Comment: I think this is a good thing. This will scale with the system.

Comment: Could you give a program (that actually compiles; what's `new buffer[VAL]`?) that illustrates the difference? Allocating n `long`s and reading/writing any of them should behave the same regardless of the size of `long`, modulo overflow of course. Portability problems only occur when you do silly things like casting pointers to `long` or doing type punning to interpret a `long` as a `float` or such.

Comment: While you're in there, why not just use the right types to begin with?  IE, why are you trying to cast a `buffer*` (actually a `void*`) to a completely unrelated type, `long*`?

Comment: Oops! Corrected it to `new long[VAL];`

Answer (score 2):

> I am confused as to what should be the replacement for the above two lines in general so that these lines work correctly both in 32-bit as well as 64-bit mode.

The answer depends on what you mean by "working correctly".

If you are looking to use integers with specific size (i.e. 32 bits on all platforms or 64 bits on all platforms) use definitions from `<cstdint>`: `int32_t` for 32 bits, `int64_t` for 64 bits. This will ensure the exact sizing regardless of the platform.

If all you need is interoperability within your own program, you can leave everything as is: in the absence of overflows on the platform with the shortest `long`, the program is going to do the same thing on the platform with longer `long`, except that it would take more memory than is necessary.

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean by "interoperability within your own program"?

Comment: @Sankalp I mean the code similar to what you have written in your post, i.e. transfers between locations of the same type, such as `var` and `buffer[0]` which are both of type `long`.